# The difference between " I ate at 7:00 AM" and " I ate from 7:00 AM"?

Tags: prepositions, time

What's the  difference  between:

> I ate at 7:00 AM.

and

> I ate from 7:00 AM.

Answer (score 2):

Variations of this question seem to come up a fairly often. What is important for English language learners to remember is that

> **X "I ate from 7:00 a.m." [grammatically OK but uncommon usage]**

is not said by native speakers of English. This construction may be used in other languages, but not in English. Now, someone may be able to think of an example where it ***could*** be used, but it is not idiomatic. It's fine to say,

> **"I ate at 7:00 a.m." [correct and common usage]**

but that doesn't mean the person was looking at his or her watch and began eating exactly at that time; it is assumed to be approximate. Likewise,

> **"I finished eating around 7:30." [correct and common usage]**

is also understood to be approximate. However, one can say,

> **"We ate from 7 until 8 this evening, then we went out for a movie." [correct and common usage]**

but again, a native speaker would not take this to mean that eating started exactly at 7:00 p.m. and ended exactly at 8:00 p.m.; once again, it is an approximation in common usage.

**As J.R. commented,** "I can understand how a learner might have trouble understanding when we can alter a sentence and still have it sound 'normal.' After all, if it's okay to say, 'We ate from 7 until 8, and then we went out,' then it stands to reason that it must be okay to say, 'I ate from 7:15 until 7:45' (except, as you point out here, no one ever talks like that). Though grammatically equivalent, one sounds natural, and the other sounds forced and contrived."

Comment: While I agree with the overall gist of this answer, I think the construct _We ate from [an approximate time] to (or until) [an approximate time]_ isn't all that unusual. For example: _We ate from 7 until 8, and then we went out for a movie_.

Comment: As an amendment to my comment, I can understand how a learner might have trouble understanding when we can alter a sentence and still have it sound "normal." After all, if it's okay to say, _"We ate from 7 until 8, and then we went out,"_ then it stands to reason that it must be okay to say, _"I ate from 7:15 until 7:45"_ (except, as you point out here, no one ever talks like that). Though grammatically equivalent, one sounds natural, and the other sounds forced and contrived.

Answer (score -1):

"I ate **at** 7:00 AM." I would assume you were eating at that time - you could have started eating at or shortly before 7:00 AM., and you likely finished eating a few minutes later.

"I ate **from** 7:00 AM." means you started eating at exactly 7:00 AM.

Both sentences are very similar, but "I ate from 7:00 AM." specifies the time that you started eating.

Comment: **ate** would be the wrong tense to use for the "started eating at" meaning. The past continuous would be idiomatic.  "I *was sitting* at my desk from 7AM onward."

Comment: @TRomano: Not so. *They eat from dawn to dusk,* and *We danced from 7pm 'til midnight* are perfectly normal constructions, and I can't see any grammatical reason why *I ate from 7am* should be considered "invalid" - it's just relatively unlikely unless conjoined with some kind of ***until*** clause.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The grammatical reason is precisely the one you mention:  the simple past with a bare **from** is not enough to convey the idea "began doing {x} starting at".  We need another complementary phrase to create the time-vector.

Comment: @TRomano: Perhaps we have a different idea of what "grammatical reason" means. There's nothing remotely unusual about *The cafe serves breakfast from 7am*, so I don't see how you can describe any kind of "rule" allowing that but debarring OP's example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You've added a direct object. Try your sentence using the verb "opens".  *The cafe opens|opened from 7am.

Comment: We wouldn't say "The surgeon operated from 7AM".

Comment: @TRomano: You might not say *The surgeon operated from 7AM*, but plenty of other people might. As for the direct object, are you suggesting *I ate **breakfast** from 7am* suddenly becomes more correct because I've specified *what* I ate? These are issues of ***idiomacy***, not grammatical rules.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think the overwhelming majority of native speakers, if they wished to convey the idea *the surgeon began operating at 7AM* would chose a verb phrase other than "operated from 7AM [full stop]". If they avoided the natural choice (**began operating**) and used the simple past **operated** + **from** to convey this idea, they would append a phrase like **on** or **onward**. Why? Because the simple past does not, in and of itself, convey the idea of *ongoing action* and neither does the preposition **from**, which conveys only the idea of *terminus a quo*.

Comment: @TRomano: I'm not trying to disagree with you about how native speakers are *likely* to express certain concepts - just the idea that idiomatic usage in these contexts *unavoidably* follows from "grammar rules".

Comment: @TRomano - _The surgeon operated from 7AM_ doesn't sound **wrong** so much as it sounds **incomplete**. (After all, I assume you don't find anything unusual with _The surgeon operated from 7AM until noon._)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But **idiomatic usage** and **grammar rules** are pretty much synonymous!  Grammar rules are abstract descriptions of idiomatic speech.

Comment: @TRomano: I guess you're right. Well, let's not beat about the bush - I *know* you're right, since in other contexts I'd be quite happy to triumphantly post your last comment myself, as the final *coupe de grace* in some "argument" on ELU/ELL!

Comment: @J.R. I would call a verb phrase *malformed* if it is missing an element necessary to establish or complete its sense. In English, verbal aspect is established lexically with periphrasis such as *began to {verb}*; some verb-phrases need a complementing "adposition" (preposition, postposition, circumposition) or other time-marker.

Comment: **The surgeon operated from 7AM** is malformed to the point where we don't even know what it might be attempting to say.  The surgeon began to operate at 7AM?  The surgeon had been operating since 7AM? The surgeon's general practice was to begin operating at 7AM?

Comment: @TRomano - We are in agreement; my comment was aimed at the learner. (I just wouldn't want a learner to read, _We wouldn't say "The surgeon operated from 7AM"_ and then conclude that "The surgeon operated from 7AM until noon" must be wrong also.)

Answer (score -1):

I think the phrase 'I ate at 7:00 AM '  means that you started eating at 7:00 AM and finished it after some time. But the phrase 'I ate from 7:00 AM' means that you started to eat at 7:00 AM and you are still eating.

Comment: I don't agree with the second part of this – especially the part where you say you're still eating.